# Is the second smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian matrix a set function over edges?

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected unweighted undirected graph. In addition, let $\lambda_2(L(G))$ be the second smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian matrix of graph $G$.

Is $\lambda_2(L(G))$ a submodular set function over the edges (for a fixed number of nodes)?

Comment: Have you checked this numerically for small cases (all graphs with $v\leq 5$, graphs near Petersen and other standard examples, etc.)?